# url for an action of a controller in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, url

I am trying to learning Zend framework. For that I have installed NetBeans IDE and download zend framework's library. I have created one small application by NetBeans IDE and place the zend framework's library under library folder. 
Under Controller folder, in IndexController.php file, I have written one action called indexAction() and there I write simply `$this->view->assign('title', 'Hello, World!');`. 
Under views/scripts/index folder create one file called index.phtml and there I have written out `<h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></h1>`.
My main folder name is `phpproject1` and under that I have created all other folders like application, library,public.

Now please suggest me how to open that action in browser?
e.g. - In codeigniter it is like : localhost://project_name/index.php/controller_name/action_name

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are learning Zend Framework, you should learn ZF2 not 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your installation is correct and you didn't configure any route. try to adapte this to your case.

```
http://lcalhost/[project_Name]/public/[Module_name]/[Controller_name]/[action_name]
```

in case you dont have Module;

```
 http://lcalhost/[project_Name]/public/[Controller_name]/[action_name]
```